# Getting some errors on python using pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer

I created a file using classes in both qt. When i run both these files seperate it works perfectly fine. (Mainmenu) and (Finder) but when i call the file i get errors. i attempted to call another file ie print hello which it does -- Import  --- .subroutine. Next i attempted exception which still when it has those two file together automatically fail no messages. I know both have the same classes due to QT designer but i dont know what to do. They both hate each other.

FILE MERGED

```
> class Ui_MainWindow(object):
>         MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
>         self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
>         QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
>     def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
>         _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
>         MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Assetto corsa car mod installer"))
>         self.dirlabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Directory"))
>         self.pathfinder.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Path Finder"))
>         self.pflabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Dont know where directory path is?                   Use our path finder"))
>         self.paste.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Paste"))
>         self.next.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Next"))
>         self.cancel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cancel"))
> 
> def starter():
>     import sys
>     app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
>     MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
>     ui = Ui_MainWindow()
>     ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
>     MainWindow.show()
>     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

FILE MAIN MENU
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap

```
class Ui_MainMenu(object):
    def nextpg(self):
        MainMenu.close()
        import MERGED
        MERGED.starter()



    def setupUimain(self, MainMenu):
        MainMenu.setObjectName("MainMenu")
        MainMenu.resize(800, 600)
        MainMenu.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("logo.png"))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainMenu)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.msg = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.msg.setObjectName("msg")
        self.msg.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.msg, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.Title = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.Title.setObjectName("Title")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Title, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.Start = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Start.setObjectName("Start")
        self.Start.clicked.connect(lambda: self.nextpg())
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Start, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.img = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.img.setObjectName("img")
        self.img.setPixmap(QPixmap("logo.png"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.img, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        MainMenu.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainMenu)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainMenu.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainMenu)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainMenu.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUimain(MainMenu)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainMenu)

    def retranslateUimain(self, MainMenu):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainMenu.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainMenu", "Assetto corsa car mod installer"))
        self.msg.setText(_translate("MainMenu", "Welcome to my program"))
        self.Title.setText(_translate("MainMenu", "H.W.K"))
        self.Start.setText(_translate("MainMenu", "Start"))
        self.img.setText(_translate("MainMenu", ""))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainMenu = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainMenu()
    ui.setupUimain(MainMenu)
    MainMenu.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If anyone finds a fix this would be very helpful as there is nothing similar online.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
# first class

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
         MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
         self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
         QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
     def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
         _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
         MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Assetto corsa car mod installer"))
         self.dirlabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Directory"))
         self.pathfinder.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Path Finder"))
         self.pflabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Dont know where directory path is?                   Use our path finder"))
         self.paste.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Paste"))
         self.next.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Next"))
         self.cancel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cancel")) 


# second class

import Ui_MainWindow as uw

class Ui_MainMenu(object):
    def nextpg(self):
        uw.show()
        

    def setupUimain(self, MainMenu):
        MainMenu.setObjectName("MainMenu")
        MainMenu.resize(800, 600)
        MainMenu.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("logo.png"))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainMenu)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.msg = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.msg.setObjectName("msg")
        self.msg.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.msg, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.Title = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.Title.setObjectName("Title")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Title, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.Start = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Start.setObjectName("Start")
        self.Start.clicked.connect(lambda: self.nextpg())
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Start, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.img = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.img.setObjectName("img")
        self.img.setPixmap(QPixmap("logo.png"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.img, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        MainMenu.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainMenu)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainMenu.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainMenu)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainMenu.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUimain(MainMenu)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainMenu)

    def retranslateUimain(self, MainMenu):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainMenu.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainMenu", "Assetto corsa car mod installer"))
        self.msg.setText(_translate("MainMenu", "Welcome to my program"))
        self.Title.setText(_translate("MainMenu", "H.W.K"))
        self.Start.setText(_translate("MainMenu", "Start"))
        self.img.setText(_translate("MainMenu", ""))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainMenu = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainMenu()
    ui.setupUimain(MainMenu)
    MainMenu.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```